# A dagger is used for a footnote in the FAQ, but there is no asterisk footnote preceding it

Tags: feature-request, design, site-faq

In the FAQ, under *[What is reputation?](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)*, there are some privileges summed up. The reputation to be able to comment everywhere has a 'strange' character behind it (†).

At first glance it looks like the rule isn't in effect any more (hence the [RIP](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/RIP#Initialism) symbol). Only you will discover it is used as a footnote symbol.

> † you can always comment on your questions and answers, and any answers to questions you’ve asked, even with 1 rep.

Can that be changed to an asterisk (*) perhaps (or something less scary ;) )?

**EDIT**

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger_%28typography%29):

> The dagger is usually used to indicate a footnote, in the same way an asterisk is. **However, the dagger is only used for a second footnote when an asterisk is already used**

**EDIT 2**

To further (and better) explain my issue with the dagger symbol:

1. It shouldn't be used in the first place (without a preceding asterisk footnote)
2. When people just see that symbol it looks the 'function' is obsolete (the other common meaning of the dagger symbol)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger_%28typography%29

Comment: Though, note that the Wikipedia article says, "[T]he dagger is only used for a second footnote when an asterisk is already used."  I don't see an asterisk already in use, so this request does have merit...

Comment: Perhaps you should modify the question to say that the confusion comes from that fact (about the dagger being secondary to the asterisk).

Comment: Not sure why Pekka deleted his answer; it was fine, and this is silly. As he correctly noted, the dagger is a recognized typographical symbol with a long history. There's nothing scary or offensive about it. I've seen the dagger and even double dagger used ahead of the asterisk, and in conjunction with numbered footnotes. The fact that one book exists that says the asterisk should be used first doesn't make it an inviolable universal law.

Comment: @PopularDemand That rule isn't about the book anymore it's about how you are suppose to use it IMHO. Like you should always start your sentence with a capital.

Comment: Interesting note about the dagger only being used after an asterisk has. I'm not sure that is how I've observed it being used, though. I can't say I recall ever seeing it used only after an asterisk was.

Comment: In fact, I seem to recall that when seeing an asterisk used for the first note, multiple asterisks are used for subsequent notes.

Comment: For more info for people interested: http://www.typography.com/ask/showBlog.php?blogID=190

Comment: I wonder if typographical questions are considered on-topic for the English Language & Usage or Writers SE sites.  The FAQs don't explicitly mention it as on- or off-topic.

Comment: I'd think yes for EL&U, @David. I was planning on asking myself, but I'm unable to log in.

Comment: @David if you do post the question there please share it here would you? Thanks

Comment: Is this a dagger I see before me?

Comment: Asked on English SE [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53691/when-a-dagger-is-used-to-indicate-a-note-must-it-come-after-an-asterisk).

Comment: Okay, apparently this is a real rule and I just wasn't aware of it. Changing my downvote to an upvote. I still think it's silly to call the symbol "strange" or "scary," though.

Comment: Just noticed that the "disputed" item in the sidebar of the "Flagging history" page is also *dagger-footnoted*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Honestly, I'm not really sure this specific example even warrants a footnote, as it only consists in a single sentence that's not overly long.

Putting it next to the text it elaborates on, maybe in smaller type, would avoid the context switch and look just as good IMHO:

> 15    Flag for moderator attention
>
> 50    Leave comments
>
> <sup>(you can always comment on your questions and answers, and any answers to questions you’ve asked, even with 1 rep)</sup>
>
> 100   Edit community wiki posts

Comment: Agreed.  It also threw me for a second that the "footnote" isn't in the footer of the document (page).  It's at the bottom of an arbitrary section of a larger section of the overall document.  Additionally, when directly linked and quotes at the top of the page for convenience, it creates a duplicate "dagger" on the page, which likely further obfuscates proper use of the symbol.

Answer (score 8):

I disagree with the Wikipedia article here: the footnote symbol order `*`, `†`, `‡`, … is common but it is not an absolute rule. In particular, in scientific or technical works, it's common to avoid symbols that are used as mathematical notations for typography, which means not using digits or `*` in footnotes.

`†` as an indication that a function is obsolete is highly specialized usage; even on Stack Overflow (which is only one of many sites in the Stack Exchange network, this isn't 2009 any more) I expect a minority of the readers to interpret it in that manner. A raised symbol which is repeated at the beginning of a line towards the bottom is a common way to mark footnotes, and as you note `†` is commonly used as a footnote symbol anyway.

Comment: `is common but it is not an absolute rule` Actually it is :)